# Electron hardware access returns wrong output, but why?

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron

Im trying to log some of the device's hardware information in the console but it simply wont work. It outputs a way to big amount for RAM and os.cpus() returns an empty array. Any ideas why? (Im using Electron)

```
var os = require('os');
console.log(os.totalmem());
console.log(os.cpus());
console.log("test")
```

This is the output:
[image]

Comment: dont mind the console.log("test")